# Coldfusion Scheduled Tasks - Does the interval reset each time a task runs?

Tags: coldfusion, time, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know that when a scheduled task in Coldfusion runs it resets the interval timer or does the task run at the set interval time no matter how long that task run for?

For example, i create a task to run every 10 minutes that takes 5 minutes to run starting from 12pm. Will the task run at 12:00, then 12:10, then 12:20 etc etc.

Or would it run at 12:00 which takes 5 minutes, then at 12:15 ten minutes after the task has finished, then another 5 minutes to run so the next one would run at 12:30 etc etc.

Hope that makes sense.

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For example, i create a task to run
>   every 10 minutes that takes 5 minutes
>   to run starting from 12pm. Will the
>   task run at 12:00, then 12:10, then
>   12:20 etc etc.

Yes.

The task will always run on the interval. So if you set it every 10 minutes it will run every 10 minutes after the first run.

**Note:** If the task runs over time (i.e. longer than the interval) than it will NOT queue. That particular run will just be skipped and the task will run at the next interval as per usual.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, just wanted confirmation.